# Counting all entries with KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Is it possible to use KSQL to not only count entries of a specific column via `GROUP BY` but instead get an aggregate over all the entries that stream through the application?

I'm searching for something like this:

```
| Count all | Count id1 | count id2 |
| ---245----|----150----|----95-----|
```

Or more like this in KSQL:

```
[some timestamp] | Count all | 245   
[some timestamp] | Count id1 | 150   
[some timestamp] | Count id2 | 95   
.   
.   
.
```

Thank you
- Tim

Comment: so in pseudo-SQL, something like `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT ID1), COUNT(DISTINCT ID2) FROM FOO`? is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that was the initial idea here. However the final idea was to simply get the whole amount of records so only count(*). @Hojjat answer seems like it's working perfectly fine!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot have both counts for the all and count for each key in the same query. You can have two queries here, one for counting each value in the given column and another for counting all values in the given column.
Let's assume you have a stream with two columns, col1 and col2.
To count each value in col1 with infinite window size you can use the following query:

```
SELECT col1, count(*) FROM mystream1 GROUP BY col1;
```

To count all the rows you need to write two queries since KSQL always needs GROUP BY clause for aggregation. First you create a new column with constant value and then you can count the values in new column and since it is a constant, the count will represent the count of all rows. Here is an example:

```
CREATE STREAM mystream2 AS SELECT 1 AS col3 FROM mystream1;
SELECT col3, count(*) FROM mystream2 GROUP BY col3;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, the second part was exactly what I was searching for! Thanks

Comment: Note that if you have a topic with high data rate aggregation with one value for key will repartition the topic and send all of the messages to one partition which may result in scaling issues. So you should be careful in using this approach.

Comment: Good to know, thank you very much.
This will be mainly used in testing, so luckily not production use.

Comment: Is there a ksql ticket for this rather obvious usecase of `COUNT` without grouping?

Comment: I don't really like the solution as it creates an orphan stream. Maybe it could be adopted to at least drop the stream after doing the counting?

Comment: will `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mystream GROUP BY 1` work?

Answer (score 3):

This works too to get total rows count for a table:

```
ksql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mytable` GROUP BY 1 EMIT CHANGES;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|KSQL_COL_0                                                                                                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2298
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do a extended describe on the stream or table to see the total messages

```
ksql> describe extended <stream or table name>
```

sample output

```
Local runtime statistics
------------------------
messages-per-sec:         0   total-messages:   2415888     last-message: 2019-12-06T02:29:43.005Z
```